# Flutter TextField autocomplete overlay

Tags: dart, flutter

I am struggling to create TextField with autocomplete overlay. 
I have form with TextFields and I want to display suggestions based on what is typed in TextField.

Something like this:
[TextField autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Da2kv.png)
I am not sure what the hierarchy of widgets should look like to achieve displaying the suggestions box above other widgets. Should I use Stack widget, OverflowBox widget or something else?

Any help by hierarchy example appreciated.

Answer (score 27):

I have implemented a package, [flutter_typeahead](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_typeahead) to do exactly that. In this package, I use [Overlay.of(context).insert](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/OverlayState/insert.html), which allows me to insert the suggestions list in the Overlay, making it float on top of all other widgets. I also wrote [this article](https://medium.com/saugo360/https-medium-com-saugo360-flutter-using-overlay-to-display-floating-widgets-2e6d0e8decb9) to explain how to do this in detail

Comment: This is perfect.
Thank you so much.

Comment: @AkramChauhan the flutter_typehead works with bloc? Could you provide us a sample how to make it with bloc?

Comment: This package is pretty good, however, is it possible to make the overlay expand to the whole screen width if the text field has a margin to its side? For example, a custom cancel button beside the text field.

Comment: Is this still the preferred solution in 2021? Still no official Flutter alternative available?

Comment: @SePröbläm there is a package in development currently: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/62927, not as mature as flutter_typeahead though

Answer (score 16):

I implemented for my app using Stack. TextFormField in one container and ListTiles in another container and overlaying the listtile  as user types on the container of text input field. You could check out [my app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ronin.googlewhacksaga).

The following sample app uses suggestions as user type from api and display in list which user can select by tapping.

[image: Valid XHTML]

[image: Valid XHTML]

[image: Valid XHTML]

[image: Valid XHTML]

[image: Valid XHTML]

Code Sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:search_suggestions/suggestions_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Suggestions Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: new ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
      ),
      home: new SuggestionsPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

class SuggestionsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SuggestionsPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _SuggestionsPageState createState() => new _SuggestionsPageState();
}

class _SuggestionsPageState extends State<SuggestionsPage> {
  static const JsonCodec JSON = const JsonCodec();

  final key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final TextEditingController _searchQueryController =
      new TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode _focusNode = new FocusNode();

  bool _isSearching = true;
  String _searchText = "";
  List<String> _searchList = List();
  bool _onTap = false;
  int _onTapTextLength = 0;

  _SuggestionsPageState() {
    _searchQueryController.addListener(() {
      if (_searchQueryController.text.isEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          _isSearching = false;
          _searchText = "";
          _searchList = List();
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _isSearching = true;
          _searchText = _searchQueryController.text;
          _onTap = _onTapTextLength == _searchText.length;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isSearching = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: key,
      appBar: buildAppbar(context),
      body: buildBody(context),
    );
  }

  Widget getFutureWidget() {
    return new FutureBuilder(
        future: _buildSearchList(),
        initialData: List<ListTile>(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ListTile>> childItems) {
          return new Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            height: getChildren(childItems).length * 48.0,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: new ListView(
//            padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0),
              children: childItems.data.isNotEmpty
                  ? ListTile
                      .divideTiles(
                          context: context, tiles: getChildren(childItems))
                      .toList()
                  : List(),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  List<ListTile> getChildren(AsyncSnapshot<List<ListTile>> childItems) {
    if (_onTap && _searchText.length != _onTapTextLength) _onTap = false;
    List<ListTile> childrenList =
        _isSearching && !_onTap ? childItems.data : List();
    return childrenList;
  }

  ListTile _getListTile(String suggestedPhrase) {
    return new ListTile(
      dense: true,
      title: new Text(
        suggestedPhrase,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2,
      ),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _onTap = true;
          _isSearching = false;
          _onTapTextLength = suggestedPhrase.length;
          _searchQueryController.text = suggestedPhrase;
        });
        _searchQueryController.selection = TextSelection
            .fromPosition(new TextPosition(offset: suggestedPhrase.length));
      },
    );
  }

  Future<List<ListTile>> _buildSearchList() async {
    if (_searchText.isEmpty) {
      _searchList = List();
      return List();
    } else {
      _searchList = await _getSuggestion(_searchText) ?? List();
//        ..add(_searchText);

      List<ListTile> childItems = new List();
      for (var value in _searchList) {
        if (!(value.contains(" ") && value.split(" ").length > 2)) {
          childItems.add(_getListTile(value));
        }
      }
      return childItems;
    }
  }

  Future<List<String>> _getSuggestion(String hintText) async {
    String url = "SOME_TEST_API?s=$hintText&max=4";

    var response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    List decode = JSON.decode(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode != HttpStatus.OK || decode.length == 0) {
      return null;
    }
    List<String> suggestedWords = new List();

    if (decode.length == 0) return null;

    decode.forEach((f) => suggestedWords.add(f["word"]));
//    String data = decode[0]["word"];

    return suggestedWords;
  }

  Widget buildAppbar(BuildContext context) {
    return new AppBar(
      title: new Text('Suggestions Demo'),
    );
  }

  Widget buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return new SafeArea(
      top: false,
      bottom: false,
      child: new SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
        child: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: new Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const SizedBox(height: 80.0),
                      new TextFormField(
                        controller: _searchQueryController,
                        focusNode: _focusNode,
                        onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
                          print("$value submitted");
                          setState(() {
                            _searchQueryController.text = value;
                            _onTap = true;
                          });
                        },
                        onSaved: (String value) => print("$value saved"),
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: const UnderlineInputBorder(),
                          filled: true,
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                          hintText: 'Type two words with space',
                          labelText: 'Seach words *',
                        ),
                      ),

                      const SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                      new Center(
                        child: new RaisedButton(
                            color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                            onPressed: () => print("Pressed"),
                            child: const Text(
                              '    Search    ',
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                            )),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 200.0),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            new Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
//                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .18,
                    top: 136.0,
                    right: 0.0,
                    left: 38.0),
                child: _isSearching && (!_onTap) ? getFutureWidget() : null)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this is the perfect solution +1. thank you @Ronin

Answer (score 13):

You can make use of [autocomplete_textfield](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/autocomplete_textfield) library to achieve that.

**Basic Usage**

```
  ...

                SimpleAutoCompleteTextField(
                  key: key,
                  suggestions: [
                    "Apple",
                    "Armidillo",
                    "Actual",
                    "Actuary",
                    "America",
                    "Argentina",
                    "Australia",
                    "Antarctica",
                "Blueberry",],
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.black12,
                    hintText: 'Dictionary'
                  ),
                ),

                ...
```

You can get more examples [here](https://github.com/felixlucien/flutter-autocomplete-textfield/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart).

**Another Option**

You can also make use of [flutter_typeahead](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_typeahead)

This worked better for me when working with `StreamBuilder`for BLoC pattern.

Comment: Have you found a way to use a validator with SimpleAutoCompleteTextField? I'm using it in an email field and I'd like to run my basic email validator on it?

Answer (score 7):

I would probably have a Container with a fixed height, containing a Column with its crossAxisAlignment set to stretch. The first child in the column would be the text field. The second would be an Expanded containing a ListView with a custom delegate to provide the children. Then, as the data in the text field changes, you update the delegate so that the children are updated. Each child would be a ListTile containing an InkWell which, when tapped, fills the text field appropriately.

Comment: Ok thanks. And if I want the suggestions to be above other widgets, should I use the `Overlay.of(context).insert(entryWithExpandedListView);`?

Comment: @guest3523 have you successfully completed your autocomplete overlay? I am trying to do the same for my app and having just 3 days of flutter experience so far, I am having a hard time with it.

Answer (score 5):

Consider using the inbuilt [RawAutoCompleteWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RawAutocomplete-class.html). It has support for all platforms and you can nest your TextField under it. I've got it working and running well with a minor hiccup that shouldn't affect most people. Will update the answer if you have any queries.

Answer (score 2):

### You can use [Autocomplete](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html) from the [material library](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/material-library.html). For Example,

**Custom Model:**

```
@immutable
class User {
  const User({
    required this.email,
    required this.name,
  });

  final String email;
  final String name;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$name, $email';
  }
}
```

**Autocomplete with custom model:**

```
class AutocompleteBasicUserExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const AutocompleteBasicUserExample({super.key});

  static const List<User> _userOptions = <User>[
    User(name: 'Alice', email: 'alice@example.com'),
    User(name: 'Bob', email: 'bob@example.com'),
    User(name: 'Charlie', email: 'charlie123@gmail.com'),
  ];

  static String _displayStringForOption(User option) => option.name;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Autocomplete<User>(
      displayStringForOption: _displayStringForOption,
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
        if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
          return const Iterable<User>.empty();
        }
        return _userOptions.where((User option) {
          return option
              .toString()
              .contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
        });
      },
      onSelected: (User selection) {
        debugPrint('You just selected ${_displayStringForOption(selection)}');
      },
    );
  }
}
```