# Flutter 'paypal downshift'

Tags: android, ios, autocomplete, dart, flutter

i'm trying to implement a autocompletion likes 
'paypal downshift'

[which country do you want to send money to?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAL5t.png)

the code looks like https://codesandbox.io/s/9rWEmzEv8...

how can i translate it in flutter? (dart)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43652460/flutter-textfield-autocomplete-overlay

Comment: Main feature of downshift is its state only library design. I am not sure flutter have render props like feature