# E-Mail field does not get recognized for user suggestions

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have a simple `TextFormField` with `keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress`. When I use this on my daily phone, I don't get my usual e-mail adress suggestions like I'm used to when using a browser and a webpage form. Is it possible to add this in Flutter?

Comment: this is your answer what you looking for [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50094074/11642248)

Comment: Sorry but this is not the answer to my question. I want suggestions coming from the users device, not showing a list of my suggestions.